# X-PATH/XSL PARSING

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

Below is input XML.

```
     <ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
          <Ticket>
            <UrgencyCode>3</UrgencyCode>
            <ImpactCode>2</ImpactCode>
          </Ticket>
     </ServiceIncident>
```

In the above input XML if am using XMLNS in the root element (i.e `ServiceIncident`) so that the elements are in the `http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2` namespace.

I am not getting any values in my output. If I remove the `xmlns` namespace declaration in the input XML then I can get values in the output.

I need to use `xmlns` in the input. How can I get values in my output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070338/xsl-transformation-from-xml-tag-with-and-without-namespaces/20070904#20070904

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behavior with xml-namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639918/strange-behavior-with-xml-namespace)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the namespace in your XSLT (with a prefix) and then use that prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:r2="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <n>
        <xsl:value-of select="r2:ServiceIncident/r2:Ticket/r2:UrgencyCode"/>
      </n>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above XSLT is run on your sample, the result is:

```
<n>2</n>
```